# Navigating between radio button doesn't work while navigating back

Tags: javascript, jquery

Requirements:

1. Click on Radio Button Agree --- Do something
2. Click on Radio Button Disagree --- Do something

It's working completely fine for first time.

The problem is occurring when clicking on the 'disagree' radio button and then again clicking 'agree'. It's not calling the functionality defined in 'agree' section (i.e. the submit button still should be in disabled mode) and vice versa. Requesting your suggestion please.

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=choice]').change(function() {
  if (this.value == 'Agree') {
    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    )
  } else if (this.value == 'Disagree') {
    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="Agree" id="agree_radio">Agree</label> label>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Disagree" id="disagree_radio">Disagree</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn" value="resp_form" disabled="disabled" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen? `event.preventDefault()` will not enable the button again

Comment: If I click for the first time Disagree, Submit button is now Enabled to submit the whole form. Now user's mood changed & he/she clicked on Agree again & now he is expecting to do something & then Submit button will be enabled to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're nesting event handlers. To fix the problem separate the logic so that you enable the button based on the chosen radio in the `change` event handler. Then have a separate handler on form submission which checks that the 'Agree' radio is checked, and prevents the event if not. Try this:

```js
var $radios = $('input[type="radio"][name="choice"]').change(function() {
  $('#submit').prop('disabled', $(this).val() === 'Disagree');
});

$('#yourForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  if ($radios.filter(':checked').val() !== 'Agree') {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('disagree checked, form submission cancelled');
  } else {
    console.log('submitting form...');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="yourForm">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Agree" id="agree_radio">
    Agree
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Disagree" id="disagree_radio">
    Disagree
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn" value="resp_form" disabled="disabled" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In theory the form should never be submit when 'Disagree' is checked as the button is disabled, but people can still mess with the DOM inspector, or hit return on the inputs to submit the form, so it's best to cover the eventuality.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code. I hope it will helps you.

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=choice]').change(function() {
  if (this.value == 'Agree') {  $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("in agreeeeee")
      }
    )
  } else if (this.value == 'Disagree') {
    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="Agree" id="agree_radio">Agree</label> 
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Disagree" id="disagree_radio">Disagree</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn" value="resp_form" disabled="disabled" id="submit">Submit</button>
```